# SQL Sub-select statements filter using where clause

Tags: mysql

I am in the process of building a dashboard and need to extract some data from a somewhat complex schema.

I have a select statement (see below) that I am using to extract information, but need to conduct some filtering on part of the select statement, and I'm struggling.

```
select distinct j.id 'Job_Id'
        , js.outcome 'Outcome'
        ,(select string from property where parent_sheet_id = ps.id and name= 'Build_Type') as 'Build_Type' 
    from job j, job_step js, property_sheet ps, property p
    where j.id = js.job_id
    and ps.entity_id=js.id
    and ps.id=p.parent_sheet_id
    and ps.entity_type='step'
    and p.name = 'Id'
    group by j.id
    order by j.id desc;
```

I am sure that there is a better way of doing this query, and I would appreciate any other suggestions, but I am mostly attempting to place a filter on the nested select statement which has an alias of "Build_Type", but when I try it appears not to work. I've read some blogs that this is not possible, so I am a little stuck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
ps.id,
Build_Type.string
from 
property_sheet as ps
left join 
property as Build_Type
on ps.id = Build_Type.parent_sheet_id and Build_Type.name = 'Build_Type'

where Build_Type....
```